# null_value mapping in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created a mapping for a `tweetb` type in a `twitter` index:

```
curl -XPUT http://www.mydomain:9200/twitter/tweetb/_mapping -d '{
  "twitter": {
    "mappings": {
      "tweetb": {
        "properties": {
          "message": {
            "type": "string",
            "null_value": "NA"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then, I put one document:

```
curl -XPUT http://www.mydomain.com:9200/twitter/tweetb/1 -d '{"message": null}'
```

Then, I tried to get the inserted doc back:

```
curl -XGET http://www.mydomain:9200/twitter/tweetb/1
```

And that returned:

```
{
  "_index": "twitter",
  "_type": "tweetb",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 2,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : { "message": null }
}
```

I was expecting `"message" : "NA"` in the `_source` field. However, it looks like `"null_value"` isn't working.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `"null_value"` field mapping does not change the value stored, rather it changes the value that is used in searches.

If you try searching for your `"message"` using `"NA"`, then it should appear in the results:

```
curl -XPOST http://www.mydomain.com:9200/twitter/tweetb/_search -d '{
  "query" : {
    "match" : { "message" : "NA" }
  }
}'
```

Of interest, it should respond with the actual value being `null`.  Now, if you add a new document whose raw value is literally `"NA"` and perform the search, then you should see *both* results returned for the above query--one with a value and the other with `null` defined.

Perhaps of similar interest, this works for other queries as well *based on how it is indexed*, which is why a lowercase `n.*` matches, but `N.*` semi-surprisingly will not match:

```
curl -XPOST http://www.mydomain.com:9200/twitter/tweetb/_search -d '{
  "query" : {
    "regexp" : { "message" : "n.*" }
  }
}'
```

Comment: +1 for extra information provided apart from answer.

Comment: one more check we can do is 'exists' query(is not null) should return documents.